# Xamarin end of support is Nov 2023 for iOS and Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, maui

We have an application built using Xamarin, running in production for last few years ( both iOS and andriod). But, recently, We have been hearing and reading that, Microsoft is sunsetting  Xamarin end of support is Nov 2023 for iOS and Android. However Microsoft will not patch/fix bugs after Nov 2022. Is this true?

Adding to this, Maui is not yet open for GA and I still see roughly 2000 open issues.
I would like to understand

- Is it true that Microsoft will not patch/fix bugs after Nov 2022
- What is the risk if we continue to stay with Xamarin until Nov 2023,while rewrite using React Native is inprogress)

Comment: Xamarin Forms will be supported for 1 year after the GA of MAUI.  Xamarin iOS and Android will continue to be supported, because MAUI is built on top of them.

Comment: **1)** If you aren't using the "Forms" part of Xamarin, then as Jason points out, your question is based on a mis-perception. Given that `.net 6` is GA, you can switch at any time from `xamarin.android` and `xamarin.ios` to `.net6-android` and `.net6-ios`. Though I wouldn't switch yet - you'll want ".net 6 multi-targetting", but so far the multi-target mobile projects assume use of Maui. **2)** [OPINION]: If you ARE using the "Forms" part of Xamarin, then understand almost all of the Maui bugs have been there all along in XF. Maui will become more stable than XF ever was. Plan to switch.

Comment: **3)** Are the X-Forms bugs causing you problems today? If not, then there is no additional risk in staying with Xamarin. OTOH, by the end of 2022, anyone still using Xamarin will likely have switched to .net 6 and Maui. So if you encounter new problems, getting help for them may become harder. **4)** If you ARE using X-Forms (not Xamarin native), then consider doing a test of Maui. Almost everything you've done will "just work" in Maui - it started from the Xamarin Forms code base.

Comment: you can fix the bug yourselft. I think you can use it nothing will be changed.there are many bugs in xamarin.forms too.

Comment: [Maui is now GA](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/05/24/net-maui-ga.aspx?m=1).

Answer (score 5):

Every Microsoft product has a lifecycle, including Xamarin. Several [forums](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15379#issuecomment-1142127597) report that Xamarin is no longer being developed after 2 years of MAUI's release.

Microsoft has now provided a clear [support policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin). However, it is recommended to migrate as soon as possible, as there seem to be few obstacles. The latest versions will be developed until **2024**.

Comment: What exactly are the risks for not upgrading? What would happen, hypothetically, if you stay in Xamarin.Forms indefinitely?

Comment: One day you won't be able to publish in play store. You can still use MDM (mobile device management) apps like Mobileiron to distribute your apk